# jQuery Tabs Issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc, tabs

jQuery tabs does not seem to work with the following code, using the 1.8.16 development bundle:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>test</title>
    <script src="../../development-bundle/jquery-1.3.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../development-bundle/ui/ui.core.js" type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script src="../../development-bundle/ui/ui.tabs.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../development-bundle/demos/demos.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../development-bundle/themes/base/ui.all.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#tabs").tabs();
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="demo">
        <div id="tabs">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#tabs-1">tabs1option</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tabs-2">tabs2option</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tabs-3">tabs3option</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="tabs-1">
                tabs1text
            </div>
            <div id="tabs-2">
                tabs2text
            </div>
            <div id="tabs-3">
                tabs3text
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I have verified that the paths to the js and css files are good. I have also tried it with the default jquery UI download to no avail. Any ideas?

Here is the output of the site:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7V9Oy.png

Comment: I can't post images. Here is the link to the output: http://i.stack.imgur.com/7V9Oy.png

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really looks to be a path issue. You said you checked the paths. According to the src attribute, your html page is two directories BELOW the development bundle directory?

As brand waffle asked: are you seeing any errors in the console?

The code you have posted works fine for me, in Safari 5.1.1, with correct paths.